# Leading (vertical space) before and after block quotes

Tags: spacing, quoting, csquotes, grid-typesetting

I'm trying to re-define the `quote` environment (triggered by `csquote's` `\blockquote`) to remove the entire (!) additional leading before and after the quote, to make sure the quotes stays in sync with the baseline grid (I'm also re-introducing quotation marks, to compensate for the loss of distinction caused by removing the white space, but that's no part of the problem).

I do know how to modify the `quote` environment, and I've managed to reduce the white space, but what I'm looking for is a way to completely remove it. This solution, for example, inspired by Herbert's reply to a similar question, still yields a distance of 13.8pt (a surplus of 1.8pt) between the text's last and the quote's first baseline, even though `\raggedbottom` is on. Any hints are appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes,lipsum,lmodern}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\listparindent=0em
                        \itemindent=\listparindent
                        \leftmargin=\parindent
                        \rightmargin=\parindent
                        \topsep=0em
                        \parsep\z@\@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\enquote{#1}#2#3#4}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-3]
\blockquote{\lipsum*[2]}
\lipsum[3-4]
\blockquote{\lipsum*[3]}
\lipsum[4-5]
\blockquote{\lipsum*[4]}
\lipsum
\blockquote{\lipsum*[5]}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\raggedbottom` is the default for `article`. Your various `\lipsum` commands (the non-starred versions) do end paragraphs, though, and a list environment starting a new paragraph will also add `\partopsep` before and after it. Therefore, add the following to your redefinition of the `quote` environment:

```
\partopsep=0em
```

As an alternative, you could use my [`quoting`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[vskip=0pt,begintext=\textooquote,endtext=\textcoquote]{quoting}

\SetBlockEnvironment{quoting}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
    dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
    id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.}

\begin{document}

\sometext
% <-- No indentation at the start of `quoting`
\blockquote{\sometext}
% <-- No indentation after `quoting`
\sometext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, `\partopsep` does the trick. The `quoting` package does look useful, but I don't think I'm going to need it in the near future, as I'm pretty happy with `csquotes`, which takes care of most of my quoting-related needs :)

Comment: I was trying to do the same in a footnote environment, to no avail. Any good suggestions ?

Comment: @desperatewritere [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.