# adjust vertical space in quoting environment to exactly one line

Tags: spacing, quoting, vertical, grid-typesetting

I am sure this must have been asked before: I want to adjust the vertical space before and after the quoted text to exactly one line. The default seems to be a little less. I am working in a double column document and the columns should stay on the same grid even if there is quotes involved.

```
\documentclass[DIV=30,12pt,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\begin{quote}
    \blindtext
\end{quote}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the first answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53287/leading-vertical-space-before-and-after-block-quotes?rq=1) I solved the problem by redefining the quote environment.

```
\documentclass[DIV=30,12pt,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\list{}{\listparindent=0em
        \partopsep=1\baselineskip
        \itemindent=\listparindent
        \leftmargin=\parindent
        \rightmargin=\parindent
        \topsep=0em
        \parsep\z@\@plus\p@}%
    \item\relax}
{\endlist}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\begin{quote}
    \blindtext
\end{quote}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to reinvent the wheel: the `quoting` package enables you to customise very easily the quoting environment with a system of keys:

```
\documentclass[DIV=30,12pt,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{indentfirst=false, leftmargin=\parindent, vskip=\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\begin{quoting}
    \blindtext
\end{quoting}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]